# Проблема с плагином Woocommerce Subscription. Как ее решить?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Привет всем!

Есть сайт на Wordpress, с которым я пытаюсь разобраться и понять в чем проблема. Суть проблемы - на сайте есть форум bbpress, а также установлен Woocommerce и платный плагин Woocommerce Subscription. Можно оформить подписку на один месяц за 15 долларов и подписку на год за 150. Есть пользователь у которого месячная подписка истекла 3 Ноября 2017 года:
[image]
Если перейти на саму подписку в интернет-магазине Woocommerce, то ее нельзя переоформить, так как система считает, что у пользователя активная подписка, хотя она просрочена:
[image]
А должно быть так:
[image]

Как решить проблему? Заранее спасибо за любую помощь!

Comment: А чего вы смотрите его подписку из-под своего аккаунта Dev? Вам надо зарегистрироваться как Dan Dan и тогда, полагаю, увидите правильное состояние его подписки

Comment: Пользователь Dev это и есть Dan Dan

Comment: Догадаться об этом невозможно )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему:

```
add_filter( 'wcs_can_user_resubscribe_to_subscription', '__return_true', 100 );
```